# How to display req.validationError on form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, ejs

I am trying to validate a sign up page using **nodejs/express**. What I really want is to display the error messages from `req.validationErrors()` to display on my form. I am using **ejs** instead of **jade**, I saw how to display the error using **.jade** with the following code but i want to know how to display the error with **.ejs**.

Here is the jade code in signup.jade:

```
ul.errors
  if errors
    each error, i in errors
      li #{error.msg}
```

and also below is the form validation code in user.js:

```
 // Form Validation
 req.checkBody('name', 'Name field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email', 'Email field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email', 'Email not valid').isEmail();
 req.checkBody('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

// Check for errors
var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
  res.render('register', {
    errors: errors,
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    password2: password2
  });
 } else {
  var newUser = new User({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    profileimage: profileImageName
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking at looping through an object of error messages and displaying each value in the li child of your ul. this snippet should help

```
<ul class="errors">        
      <% if(errors){ %>
          <% for(var error in errors){ %>
              <li class="alert alert-danger"> <% =error %></li>
          <% } %>
      <% } %>

    </ul>
```

see the EJS Template for more details [Here](http://ejs.co/#docs)